# Getting date from timestamp: wrong date in php

Tags: php, date

i am trying to get date from a timestamp which is coming from an api ,but it will shows the wrong date.

```
<?php 
//its from the api also its timestamp of the today 
$timestamp="1460364355000";
 //  but it will shows the wrong date.
echo date('Y/m/d',$timestamp);

?>
```

When i check the above timestamp [this website](http://www.timestampconvert.com/) it will shows the correct date ,but using  php i will get the wrong date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide the timestamp by 1000, this is to remove milliseconds from the timestamp.

```
<?php
    $timestamp=1460364355000/1000;
    echo date('Y/m/d',$timestamp);
?>
```